# Django settings USE_TZ, TIME_ZONE and django rest framework

Tags: django, datetime, django-rest-framework, django-timezone

In Django tutorials, there is a sentence described like below.

> TIME_ZONE
>
> ...
>
> When USE_TZ is False, this is the time zone in which Django will store
>   all datetimes. When USE_TZ is True, this is the default time zone that
>   Django will use to display datetimes in templates and to interpret
>   datetimes entered in forms.
>
> ...

When django rest framework takes the naive datetime data from request. Then Django will interpret this naive datetime to aware local datetime of TIME_ZONE setting? And if it is right, how does it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, an input timezone is determined in DRF while parsing the request in the [serializer's `DateTimeField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield) (similar to form fields).

You can control the format of such input, and there's even a general setting [`DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#datetime_input_formats) which defaults to `['iso-8601']`.

This basically means that the input can both omit and specify the time zone using the [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format and [the field will generally be able to determine whether to create an aware or naive `datetime` object](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/bbe0df2916fd3b957eb73250533e9bdfc7f7d908/rest_framework/fields.py#L1098-L1113), according to your Django settings.

It will not attempt to convert a naive `datetime` to aware **if `timezone` attribute is set to `None`**, nor will it attempt to convert an aware timezone to a naive **if the attribute is not `None`**.

The attribute defaults to [`TIME_ZONE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_TZ) if [`USE_TZ`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE) is True, otherwise it is `None`; and can also be overridden explicitly, in a field initialisation.

***note:*** *someone should send a PR to DRF to document this behavior.*

For more info see [Django's time zone documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones)

Comment: Hello I also have this problem where date time from DRF is not convert to timezone aware. Could you kindly explain the step to fix this? I couldn't understand what setting should I use to able to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: @Norak The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones) say to set [`USE_TZ = True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones). Make sure to also set `TIME_ZONE` to the desired value.

Comment: I set it this way and seem like it not working. Here my setting with timezone: `USE_TZ = True` `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'`

Comment: At least for the current versions of Django/DRF it seems all should work well. I suggest you ask a short [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question.

Answer (score 3):

> Then Django will interpret this naive datetime to aware local datetime
>   of TIME_ZONE setting?

Django makes native datetime timezone aware at template/form level, because templates/forms are not used in Django restframework views, Django will not convert the datetimes.

In Django REST Framework, like vanilla Django, you have to set `USE_TZ` and `TIME_ZONE` to activate the timezone settings, otherwise no conversion will be done.

However until v3.8.0(released in May, 2018), Django REST Framework only convert timezone during the parsing stage(json -> model) , not in the rendering stage(model -> json). That confused a lot of people.