# Django model datetime is different in template than the database

Tags: python-3.x, django, datetime, django-models, python-datetime

The date data added is normally added to the database. There is a 3 hour difference in appearance.

This is my saved data on admin panel: [image]

The view of that data on a template: [image]

**Settings:**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tr'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Istanbul'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

**Python version:** 3.8.3

**Django version:** 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this;

```
USE_TZ = False
```

look these;

[Django settings USE_TZ, TIME_ZONE and django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365067/django-settings-use-tz-time-zone-and-django-rest-framework)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/